# How to retrieve data from data table dynamically?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a datatable like so:

```
|quotes|
|quote_a|
|quote_b|
|quote_c|
```

I want to retreive all these quotes from data table and pass them in a json request body. Now I know how to do grab each individual item via `data.get(0)`, `data.get(1)` and `data.get(2)` but this isn't really dynamic.

i want to use a dynamic way of retrieving all quotes from the data table, placing them in an away with a comma separate and place all of that in the body.

How can I change the below to achevice this?

```
@When("^get quote)
    public void getQuotes(DataTable dataTable)
        throws Throwable
{

        List<List<String>> data = dataTable.raw();
        List<String> quotesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String quotesStr : data) {
            quotesList.add(quotesStr);
        }

        requestSpecificationFacade.body("{\n" +
           " \"quoteId\": " + data.get(0) + ", " + data.get(1) + ", " + data.get(2) +  "\n" +
                                            "}");


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have a list of string and want to transform it to a single string separated by comma (and space) dynamically.

You can do this using **Java 8** with `String.join` :

```
String output = String.join(", ", data);
requestSpecificationFacade.body("{\n" +
                   " \"quoteId\": " + output +  "\n" +
                                                    "}");
```

Or using **Java 7** with a `StringBuilder` :

```
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String quote : data) {
    outputBuilder.append(quote);
    outputBuilder.append(", ");
}
String output = outputBuilder.toString();

// Remove last comma
output = output.substring(0, output.length() - ", ".length());

requestSpecificationFacade.body("{\n" +
           " \"quoteId\": " + output +  "\n" +
                                            "}");
```

In both case `output` will return `quote_a, quote_b, quote_c`.